# SQL INSERT - how to execute a list of queries automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, automation, windows-services

I've never done this, so apologies if I'm being quite quite vague.

### Scenario

I need to run a long series of `INSERT` SQL queries. This data is inserted in a table for being processed by a web service's client, i.e. the data is uploaded on a different server and the table gets cleared as the process progresses.

### What I've tried

I have tried to add a delay to each `Insert` statement like so

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00'

INSERT INTO TargetTable (TableName1, Id, Type) SELECT 'tablename1', ID1 , 1 FROM tablename1

WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00'

INSERT INTO TargetTable (TableName2, Id, Type) SELECT 'tablename2', ID2 , 1 FROM tablename2
```

But this has the disadvantage of assuming that a query will finish executing in 30 minutes, which may not be the case.

### Question

I have run the queries manually in the past, but that's excruciatingly tedious. So I would like to write a program that does that for me. 
The program should:

1. **Run each query in the order given**
2. **Wait to run the next query until the previous one has been processed, i.e. until the target table is clear**.

I'm thinking of a script that I can copy into the command prompt console, SQL itself or whatever and run.

How do I go about this? Windows service application? Powershell function?

I would appreciate any pointers to get me started.

Comment: Can you just use a DOS batch file and OSQL command line SQL tool to submit your SQL ? Is there a need to make this more complex ?

Comment: @PhillipH Hi, absolutely no need to make this more complex than necessary. I have written a batch file before, but it's the first time I heard of the OSQL tool. Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: this is documented here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012(v=sql.80).aspx and is supplied with SQL Server. It allows you to connect to and execute T-SQL against a server. Its the command-line equivalent to the Query Window in SQL Server Enterprise Manager.

Comment: I see, thank you. But how would I make sure that each query is processed before running the next one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to schedule job in SQL Server

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/create-and-schedule-a-job-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to add another service on the server, because the server is not mine.